# Open paypal digital flow lighbox on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, express-checkout

I want to initiate paypal payment for digital goods on click of button .
But since I am integrating multiple payment gateways I cannot use submit button instead I am using simple buttons and trigger the payment by sending the data to be required action according to which payment is selected.

But paypal DG js expects that button to trigger the payment should directly submit the payment

Here is my pseudo code

```
<form action ='' method='POST'>
 <input type='text' name='quantity' value=''>
 </form>

 <input type='button' value='Gateway1'/ id='gateway1'>
 <input type='button' value='Gateway2'/ id='gateway2'>
 <input type='button' value='paypalsubmit'/ id='paypal_submit'>


 $.getScript('https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js',function()   {
   //bind paypal iframe
   var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow().settrigger({
                                id:'paypal_submit'  
                         });
            });
 $('#gateway1').click({
   //submit form to checkout url for gateway1
 })
 $('#gateway2').click({
   //submit form to checkout url for gateway2
 })
 $('#paypal_submit').click({
   // Here I want to open the paypal DG BOX

 })
```

Please not that form has no submit button and I am serializing the data and sending it to required url.

How can I open the paypal DG flow on click of button.?

Answer (score 2):

PayPal digital goods just requires a button with `id` field.

```
<script src ='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({
// the HTML ID of the form submit button which calls setEC
trigger: "paypal_submit"
});
</script>
```

Once you generated the Express Checkout token you will need to pass the token to the image with `id`.

So,

```
 $('#paypal_submit').click({
   // Here I want to open the paypal DG BOX
    <a id='paypal_submit' href='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=" . YOUR_EC_TOKEN."'><img src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif' border='0' /></a>
 });
```

Comment: so do I need to change the href of anchor and append token ?

Comment: yes, if its live change to `https://www.paypal.com/incontext?token=` and append EC-token

Comment: I think you are saying that I should create a button

Comment: Is there way I can handle this at run time

Comment: you mean without creating any buttons, you want to show a paypal DG lightbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69881/discussion-between-alwayslearn-and-vimal).